# Infinity: the set of all natural numbers and their odd and even subsets

Tags: calculus

As a layman, my understanding of this concept in terms of formal mathematics is uncertain. Is it mathematically correct to say that the set of all even or odd natural numbers are half as large as the set of all natural numbers? In other words, can we quantify infinities when by definition, infinity isn't quantified? I have more questions but this will facilitate the process.

Thanks

Comment: Nope, that's the magic of infinity. We define relative size based on whether we can pair up members from sets together in an inclusive way. In other words, if there is a bijection between sets, there are the same number of elements. Clearly, the bijective map $n\to 2n$ serves this function for the evens, and $n\to 2n-1$ for odds. There's no great way to quantify the "half" nature of the evens in the naturals, unless you want to consider successive but finite subsets of the naturals.

Comment: You can't really say that the even/odd subsets of the natural numbers occupy a particular percentage of all these numbers, since all these sets are infinite.  Mathematically, you would say that the even (or odd) numbers have the same cardinality as the set of all the natural numbers.

Comment: Mathematicians would usually not say that the set of even or odd natural numbers are half as large as the set of all natural numbers. However, this is just the usual way to measure size of a set, with what we call the [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of that set. There are other ways to measure sizes of sets, [particularly sizes of subsets of $\Bbb{N}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density), which yield different results.

Comment: For a light introduction to some of this, see the small book Stories About Sets, by Vilenkin.